# How to continue asking user for input until it is considered valid?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is meant to ask a user to pick which household animal that is preferred. The answer should be either *"cats"* or *"dogs"*.

```
household_animal = (input("Which household animal do you prefer?"))
if household_animal in ("cat", "dog"):
    print("Thanks for your input on which household animal you prefer!")
else:
    print("This is not a household animal, please pick again.")
```

I am uncertain about how to make the program continue to ask for input until the user picks either *"cat"* or *"dog"*. If correct input is detected, it should no longer ask for more input.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hint: You'll need to loop back around and ask the question again if it's not one of the answers you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask **iteratively** using a loop:

```
household_animal = input("Which household animal do you prefer?")
while household_animal not in ("cat", "dog"):
    print("This is not a household animal, please pick again.")
    # pick again
    household_animal = input("Which household animal do you prefer?")
print("Thanks for your input on which household animal you prefer!")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

Since you will need to keep asking for input until a suitable animal has been chosen, you should introduce some form of loop until that condition is met.

There are many ways to write such functionality, but what you are looking for is something such as the below.

```
household_animal = None
```

```
while household_animal not in ("cat", "dog"):
    if household_animal is not None:
      print ("This is not a household animal, please pick again.")

    household_animal = input ("Which household animal do you prefer?")

print ("Thanks for your input on which household animal you prefer!")
```

> **Note**:  The code will loop until `household_animal` is either `"cat"` or `"dog"`, and display an error message *if* the user has written something which is not one of the two.